# Razor WebMail - naming attached file

Tags: asp.net, razor, email-attachments, webmail

I have a script using Razor syntax which sends confirmation to a client after processing their order.  Various PDFs may be attached, depending upon their order.

I have no problem attaching the PDF using the suggested code from Microsoft:

```
var filesList = new string[] { InsuranceIndemnityPath, tourPDFPath };
WebMail.Send(
    to: email,
    from: "me@domain.com",
    isBodyHtml: true,
    subject: "Your Booking",
    body: header + body + entry + footer,
    filesToAttach: filesList
    );
```

However, the attached files come through with the complete relative path eg in my email the attached file is something like "Docs/2015/11/InsuranceIndemnity.pdf"

I've searched on this, an so far drawn a blank on how to supply a sensible filename for the attached document(s).  Apologies if this is obvious and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, answered my own question - for the benefit of anybody else searching for this.
using Server.MapPath is the answer, and the final email contains just the actual document name, eg

```
var filesList = new string[no-of-docs-to-attach];
filesList[1] = Server.MapPath(tourPDFPath);
filesList[2] = Server.MapPath(InsuranceIndemnityPath);
WebMail.Send ( etc;
```